# how to create a batch file to directly open the java console?

Tags: java, console-application

how can i create a ".bat" file to directly open the java console to write the programs?

for example:

`c:\cd \program files\java\jdk1.6\bin`

now ive entered the above mentioned folder, after that if i have to write a program a will type "edit"

i.e- `c:\program files\java\jdk1.6\bin> edit`

After doing all this, an application opens to write the programs....

Comment: Depending on what your needs are, you may want to look at Groovy, which does have a console, which is built on java.

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't have an interactive console for writing programs. You create them in any text editor (and there are hundreds of them to choose from), compile them via the `javac` compiler (usually, there are alternatives), and run them via the `java` command (or by wrapping them up as executable jar files).

There are development environments like [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org), and many many others that can make some aspects of this more convenient (like a button click to compile and run, code auto-completion, pop-up API reference, etc.).

Comment: seriously you probably don't really want to be typing java programs in a REPL